# angular state get param child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

How can I get a param from child?

This is what I do:

```
$state.go('demo.content', {proces: '10'})
```

And then in controller 'Main' I need the value of param proces.

```
.state('demo', {
            url: '/',
        abstract: true,
            views: {
                'main': {
                    templateUrl: './App/main.html',
                    controller: 'Main'
                }
        })

.state('demo.content', {
            url: '/monitoring',
            views: {
                'chart': {
                    templateUrl: './App/chart.html',
                    controller: 'Chart'
                },
                'grid': {
                    templateUrl: './App/grid.html',
                    controller: 'Grid'
                },
        params: {proces: '4'}
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point here is, that any call to `'demo.content'` with different param **`process`** should re-call/re-init the controller of such state view.

Other words, only controllers which are part of this state, could consume the `process` as a part of injected params.

So, if there is really any part in main controller, which needs handle (changing) process id, it should be moved to the `demo.content` state, as another view

If this is the true, the best we can do is to move that view from parent into state:

```
.state('demo.content', {
    url: '/monitoring',
    views: {
        'chart': {
            templateUrl: './App/chart.html',
            controller: 'Chart'
        },
        'grid': {
            templateUrl: './App/grid.html',
            controller: 'Grid'
        },
        // this would do the stuff fro main controller
        // based on changing params
        'mainProcessor': {
            templateUrl: './App/mainProcessor.html',
            controller: 'mainProcessor'
        }
```

This, and only this way, you can be sure, that different param value will trigger the "mainProcessor" controller and allow him to do the job